# How to get shuch effect of AppBar title in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How I can get such effect of AppBar title, sample:

[image: Sample]

The big title "Coffee shop" disappears when page scrolls and appears in appBar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you need [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

- You can also check [this](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe) tutorial

An example based on the article:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MainCollapsingToolbar());
  }
}

class MainCollapsingToolbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainCollapsingToolbarState createState() => _MainCollapsingToolbarState();
}

class _MainCollapsingToolbarState extends State<MainCollapsingToolbar> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double offset = 0.0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        offset = _scrollController.offset;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 200.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: (offset == 0) ? false : true,
                  title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                  TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black87,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: "Tab 1"),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline), text: "Tab 2"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                pinned: true,
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Center(
            child: Text("Sample text"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested a lot of examples of using the slivers, but did not find a suitable one. I need to get exactly the same effect as in the example.

Comment: The problem is placing a large header. There is an option to use a sliver with a FlexibleSpaceBar, but I get an “error” described here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23864

Comment: I don't think you will find exactly the same example. You have to experiment a little bit to figure out how you can fix it. I updated the answer with an example based on the Medium article. Hope it will help

Comment: Using a ScrollController and checking the scroll status is a solution. Thank!